# Predictive Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima, vector-autoregression

Which model should i use to to analyze how well the independend variable x_t at the time t  can forecast my dependend variable at K forecasting horizons and what are the steps to take to get the benchmark results (R², slope estimates) for the forecasting results of each independend variable? I'm a bit lost here.
\begin{equation}
\ r_{t+1,t+K} = a_K + b_Kx_t+u_{t+1,t+K}
\end{equation}

Thanks for you answer!

PS: I use Matlab

Answer (score 0):

http://autobox.com/dave/regvsbox.pdf (which I authored) discusses issues/differences/opportunities/pitfalls when dealing with time series that  possible regression solutions may be ignoring.

With time series data you have "complications/opportunities" to deal with

1. needed lag structures
2. time trends
3. step/level shifts
4. seasonal pulses
5. changes in model parameters over time
6. changes in model error variance over time

Comment: Thanks for this answer! But do you know which model i should choose for my specific task?

Comment: It is impossible to pre-specify the model as it has to be found via diagnostic checking and sophisticated hypothesis generation. I don't believe MATLAB is useful in this regard.